# Unable to match after backslash in a regex

Tags: regex

I want to detect the whole of this string:

> Datensatz: MQB-A MQ200-6F DQ200-7F (V37x2PK) 1,2l 81kW V23 VCOD
>   ...027CJ_V37x2PKM27B60HF4_C\MQB-A MQ200-6F DQ200-7F (V37x2PK) 1,2l
>   81kW V23 VCOD ...027CJ_V37x2PKM27B60HF4_C

I have generated this regx:

```
(Datensatz:|Projekt:)[\s\w*,*\-\(\)\.]*[\\]*[\w]*
```

But it detect only two letters after `\`. How should I change my regex to detect the whole string?

Comment: It's unclear from your description, but I think you need just: `(Datensatz:|Projekt:)[\s\w,().\\-]*`. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nX8iZ1/1).

Comment: What is the requirement for the nature of the string after Datensatz or Project?  Because if you are just looking for strings that start with either of those two words, simply **(Datensatz:|Projekt:).***  with *dot does not match linebreak* might be all you need.

Comment: It finds 3 characters after `\ `, because the fourth (`-`) is not matched by `\w`. Your regex seems a bit weird and looks like you don't understand what happens in the character class. Maybe you can tell us what you want to achieve, then we would be able to help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it matches the whole,

```
(?:Datensatz:|Projekt:)[\s\w,*\-().]*[\\]*[\w-\s(),.]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mM8fF9/6)

[Your regex](http://regex101.com/r/mM8fF9/7) `(?:Datensatz:|Projekt:)[\s\w*,*\-\(\)\.]*[\\]*[\w]*` stops before the `-` because you included `[\\]*` in between which matches the literal backslash. After that, it will match only the words, so that it stops before `-`